# Nilpotency class of any epimorphic image of a p-group of maximal class

Tags: group-theory, p-groups

Let G be a finite p-group of maximal class. Then I was able to prove that the quotient group G/Z(G) is also of maximal class. But how can one prove that any epimorphic image of G is again of maximal class?

Comment: This is straightforwadr, and you should really try and solve it yourself. If $|G| = p^n$, then maximal class means that $G$ has class $n-2$. Consider the upper central series of $G$ and of $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: For G/Z(G), I could prove it. But what about G/N, where N is any normal subgroup of G?

Comment: Well, if $n \ge 3$, then $|Z(G)|=p$ and $N \cap Z(G) \ne 1$, so $Z(G) \le N$, and you could do it by applying induction to $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint @ Derek Holt